# Update Grid Store on Row Editing

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to update the store on RowEditing Update click

Added a Listeners as

> ```
>  listeners: {                                            
>                'edit': function (editor, e) { 
>                     alert('Row Updating');
>                  }
>             }
> ```

Alert is firing on UPdate click so tried to update the store now as below

> ```
> 1.var rec = e.record;                                                
>   e.store.sync();
> ```

```
2. var timeGrid = this.up('grid');
   timeGrid.store.sync();

3. Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gdItemId')[0].store.sync();

4. this.store.sync();
```

All the above is failing to update the changed records to store.
It is throwing error as -

> ```
> Unhandled exception at line 1984, column 17 
> 0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: unknown exception
> ```

What would be the reason? Please suggest me, how can i update the data here.

**Updating :**

Adding complete code -

> ```
>  Ext.define('TimeModel', {
> extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
> fields: [
>     { name: 'stop_type_id', type: 'int' }
> ]
> });
> ----------------------
> var storeStop = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
> fields: ["value", "text"],
> data: [
>   [1, "Delivery"],
>   [2, "Pickup"]
> ]
> });
> ---------------------------
> var comboBoxStopRenderer = function (comboStop) {
> return function (value) {
>     var idx = comboStop.store.find(comboStop.valueField, value);
>     var rec = comboStop.store.getAt(idx);
>     return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(comboStop.displayField));
> };
> }
> ------------------------
> var comboStop = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
> store: storeStop,
> valueField: "value",
> displayField: "text"
>  });
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  xtype: 'grid',
>  itemId: 'gdTimeCommitmentItemId',
>  store: {
> type: 'webapi',
> api: {
>     read: 'api/Report/GetTime'
> },
> autoLoad: false,
> },
> columns: [
>         {
>             text: 'Stop Type', dataIndex: 'stop_type_id', width: '12%', editor: comboStop, renderer: comboBoxStopRenderer(comboStop)
>         }
>     ],
>  plugins: [rowEditingTime],
>  tbar: [
> {
> text: 'Add',    
> handler: function () {
>     rowEditingTime.cancelEdit();
>     var timeGrid = this.up('grid');
>     var r = Ext.create('TimeModel', {
>         stop_type_id: 1
>     });
>     timeGrid.store.insert(0, r);
>     rowEditingTime.startEdit(0, 0);        
> }
> } ],                                      
> listeners: {                                            
> 'edit': function (editor, e) {
>     //alert('Updating');
>     //var rec = e.record;                                                
>     //e.store.sync();
>     //var timeGrid = this.up('grid');
>     //timeGrid.store.sync();
>    // Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gdTimeCommitmentItemId')[0].store.sync();
>     //this.store.sync();
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Include your store proxy class in your question. I think you didn't created your store proxy correctly.

example Store proxy for the Sync

```
   proxy : 
{
    type : 'ajax',
    reader : 
    {
        root : 'data',
        type : 'json'
    },
    api : 
    {
        read : '/ExampleService.svc/students/',
        create: '/ExampleService.svc/createstudentbatch/',
        update : '/ExampleService.svc/updatestudentbatch/',
        destroy : '/ExampleService.svc/deletestudentbatch/'
    },
    actionMethods : 
    {
        destroy : 'POST',
        read : 'GET',
        create : 'POST',
        update : 'POST'
    }}
```

Comment: your grid store app have read only.  api: {
    read: 'api/Report/GetTime'
}  where is the  update api.  refer this link http://www.extjs-tutorial.com/extjs-examples/crud-in-extjs-4-grid-example

Comment: Here i am trying to update the store locally and on page Save click button getting value from store to Database.
On RowEditing - Update : I want to update the store and not to DB. 
RowEditing  - Add - works fine here.

Comment: If you see the ADD code - i am adding the new record to the grid store. Same way how can i update the store?

Comment: you want update store locally than no need call Sync method. Sync method will invoke Db calls. Rowediting will automatically take care your update operation on existing store.put a console log and see your store is updated  after edit.

Comment: Please bear with me. 
where i need to put the console log? shall i put it in listener event?

Comment: some think like this  listeners: {                                            
'edit': function (editor, e) {
console.log("store",Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gdTimeCommitmentItemId')[0].store);
}

Comment: Not able to add the console but what i observed here is - under 
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gdTimeCommitmentItemId')[0].store.data.items[0].data
I am not seeing any updated data

Comment: How to identify the root cause here?

Comment: it should work. Can you share a Fiddle that demonstrates the issue? https://fiddle.sencha.com